# jwplayer player not working if playlist is added

Tags: javascript, php, media-player, jwplayer

i have following jwplayer code without playlist which works just fine but i want to add playlist on the rightside of player.

working jwplayer without playlist.

```
              <script type=\'text/javascript\'>
              jwplayer(\'player5PdfeedXun0ZaBZpa\').setup({
     file: \'http://www.xyz.com/mvideo/mv/'.$row2['url'].'\',
    image: \''.$row2['thumb'].'\',
    title: \''.$row2['title'].'\',
    width: \'60%\',
    aspectratio: \'16:9\',
    fallback: \'false\',
    autostart: \'true\'
    });
</script>
```

for adding playlist i am trying this as per jwplayer documentation but its not working.

```
            <script type=\'text/javascript\'>
        jwplayer(\'player5PdfeedXun0ZaBZpa\').setup({
    file: \'http://www.xyz.com/mvideo/mv/'.$row2['url'].'\',
    image: \''.$row2['thumb'].'\',
    title: \''.$row2['title'].'\',
    width: \'60%\',
    aspectratio: \'16:9\',
    fallback: \'false\',
    autostart: \'true\'

  playlist: [{
    image: \'heart.jpg\',
    file: \'/assets/sintel.mp4\',
    title: \'Sintel Movie Trailer\'
   },{
    image: \'hate.png\',
    file: \'/assets/bunny.mp4\',
    title: \'Big Buck Bunny Movie Trailer\'
}],
playlist.position:\'bottom\',
paylist.size:\'90\',
plugin:hd
   });  
   </script>
```

where i am doing mistake any idea????
when i add playlist then even player dont appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28842/working-with-playlists), you are pretty close in your code. But there's a couple of things needed to get this working.

1. For a playlist, you don't need the file, image, or title parameters since those are loaded from each track in the playlist.
2. Your JavaScript is missing a comma after `autostart: \'true\'`
3. The `playlist.position` and `playlist.size` parameters are the old way of doing things. Instead, use `listbar`.
4. I see that you tried specifying `plugins:hd`. You don't need that line unless you specify HD versions of the videos. But if you want to use HD, check out the [plugins documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31152/hd-plugin) which shows how to use that parameter.

Here's the final code:

```
<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
jwplayer(\'player5PdfeedXun0ZaBZpa\').setup({
  width: \'60%\',
  aspectratio: \'16:9\',
  fallback: \'false\',
  autostart: \'true\',
  \'playlist\': [{
    image: \'heart.jpg\',
    file: \'/assets/sintel.mp4\',
    title: \'Sintel Movie Trailer\'
   },{
    image: \'hate.png\',
    file: \'/assets/bunny.mp4\',
    title: \'Big Buck Bunny Movie Trailer\'
  }],
  listbar: {
      position: \'bottom\',
      size: 90
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: playlist is appering but movie is showing error and its not playing .yes i have added file link in ur above code

Comment: Make sure that the `file` paths for each playlist item are correct. And because of the way the rest of the code is formatted, you need to make sure the path is inside of `\'`. Example: `file: \'uploads/bunny.mp4\'` if the videos are in a subfolder called 'uploads'. Or if the videos are in a different folder, you might need to make the path absolute (with a beginning slash). Example: `file: \'/media/videos/bunny.mp4\'`.

Comment: You should also provide a link to where it isn't working so we can debug the error.